# Customize ".config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css" file based on individual applications

Tags: gnome, nautilus, themes, gtk

Is it possible either to have different **gtk.css** files to be loaded when different applications launches (e.g. *Gedit*, *Gnome-terminal*, *Nautilus*, etc.), or have specific tags in the file `.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` that act only on individual apps?

For example I would like to use the following for *gnome-terminal* app:

```
headerbar.titlebar {
    border-top: 6px solid lightgreen;
    border-left: 6px solid lightgreen;
    border-right: 6px solid lightgreen;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

and the following for the *nautilus* app:

```
headerbar.titlebar {
    border-top: 0px solid lightgreen;
    border-left: 0px solid lightgreen;
    border-right: 0px solid lightgreen;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

I was thinking to a way to make the [gtk-inspector](https://blog.gtk.org/2017/04/05/the-gtk-inspector/) to load automatically for each individually app of my interest with some custom **css** code...

Is it possible somehow to reach a such goal?

Comment: Have you read this discussion on the topic? https://discourse.gnome.org/t/how-to-apply-css-per-application/11382

Comment: @johnandmegh Yep, I already seen that post...but I can't figure out how to use `window.nautilus-window` in the `gtk.css` file.